# Database of pictures deleted from Wikipedia/Commons, and the reason for their deletion

Tags: data-request, wikimedia-commons

Hundreds of pictures are uploaded to Commons everyday, and among them many get deleted for various reasons (copyright infringement, obscenity, selfies, etc).

For machine learning purposes, I need a representative sample of thousands of these deleted pictures.

For each picture:

- The picture itself, or at least a thumbnail of it.
- The deletion reason

Is there such a publicly accessible database somewhere? If possible reasonably recent.

Comment: Do you specifically need images deleted from Wikipedia, or would you be happy with a similar database from a different website?

Comment: @csk: Specifically Wikimedia Commons.